# Does the negative apply before or after an exponent

Tags: arithmetic

I have been having an argument with a friend, and they claim $-8^0$ is $1$, and I claim that $-8^0$ is really $-(8^0)$ and is therefore $-1$. Who is right?

Answer (score 28):

Neither of you is right - or at least, you are both half right.. $$-8^0=-8^{1/2-1/2}=\frac{-8^{1/2}}{-8^{1/2}}$$ Now we compromise so that everyone gets an equal chance: $$\frac{-2\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt 2 i}={-1\over i}=i$$ So the answer is $i$. The imaginary unit. The enigma of the conundrums. The unspeakable number.

I have divulged this information at great risk to our agents in the field. Please use this remarkable knowledge with discretion, and always remember: **use more parentheses.**

Comment: I just want to say i love this answer, for its simultaneous insanity and reason

Comment: Um... please explain how you are not assuming the friend's approach from the second equality (in the first line) of this answer?

Comment: @anorton: You're right, he really should've used the compromise approach there too, and declared that $-8^{1/2-1/2}=-\frac{-8^{1/2}}{-8^{1/2}}$, which finally leads to the conclusion that $-8^0 = -i$. But that's fine, since it's really just another branch of the same multivalued function. ;-)

Comment: Whoooooooooosh. *sound of point going over heads*

Answer (score 27):

Exponents take precedence over multiplication. Your friend is wrong.

Comment: So by process of elimination, _user144807 is correct_.

Comment: It should be noted that this is simply a convention -- there's no mathematical reason why it would *have* to be so. Nonetheless, this convention is pretty much universally accepted, so that any mathematician would understand $-a^b$ as $-(a^b)$, not as $(-a)^b$. It does have the convenient advantage that it lets us write polynomials without having to stuff them full of parentheses whenever a coefficient happens to be negative. On the other hand, plenty of formulas involving alternating sums like $\sum_k (-1)^k f(k)$ would get simpler if it were the other way, so...

Comment: Without a natural order, any complicated mathematical expression could have countless possible interpretations and unique answers. While there is no mathematical reason for this, it is clearly necessary to establish an order.

Comment: @SimonT We would have to eliminate all other possibilities to use the process of elimination, and $-8^0$ could be *anything*.

Comment: I've actually had someone once tell me their calculator was broken, showing me $-4^2 = -16$ on the screen and saying that it was wrong because "the sign doesn't matter when squaring" etc etc... I added the brackets and gave the calculator back, and he understood.

Comment: http://www.mathstat.strath.ac.uk/basicmaths/124_precedence.html for  a link to the order. strath.ac.uk is a University in the UK

Comment: "precedence over multiplication" So you consider negation a kind of multiplication? One *could* have chosen a convention where $-a^b$ meant $(-a)^b$ and still have multiplication lower in precedence, such that $-ca^b$ still meant $-(c(a^b))$ or equivalently $(-c)(a^b)$, **not** $(-(ca))^b$ or $((-c)a)^b$.

Comment: **Challenge:** Find any knowledge engine that interprets $-a^b$ as $\left(-a\right)^b$. You won't; this is because there must exist a natural order of precedence in mathematical expressions. There is no point in a calculation when it can be interpreted in ways resulting in completely different answers.

By the way, negation **is** just multiplication by $-1$; thus, $-8^0 \Leftrightarrow \left(-1\right)\left(8^0\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, operations are done in this order:

1. Brackets
2. Exponents
3. Division and Multiplication
4. Addition and Subtraction

For example, $10 + 0 \times 5$ isn't read as "$10 + 0 = 10$, $10 \times 5 = 50$", it's read as "$0 \times 5 = 0$, $10 + 0 = 10$".

Your example is slightly trickier as you have to recognize what the minus sign really means. "$-n$" is essentially shorthand for $0-n$, and realizing that makes the answer clear.

Your equation is "really" $0-8^0$. Looking at the list from earlier, we see that exponents are done before subtraction, so that step comes next. $0-8^0$ becomes $0-1$, which we write as $-1$. You are correct.

Really, though, the question is less than ideal. Writing it as $-(8^0)$, as you say, would clear up a lot of problems. It's very easy to misread or misunderstand a problem and steps clearly were never taken to avoid that here.

Comment: One might also say that $-n$ is shorthand for $(-1)n$, which of course does not change the answer.

Comment: @jpm I can't think of any situations where $0-n \neq (-1)n$ (for $n \in \mathbb{R}$, at least) so having different ways to think about it is always good. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: without parenthesis around the **(−8)**, the formula **−8<sup>0</sup>** is equivalent to **(−1) * (8<sup>0</sup>)**.

You trying to determine whether the equation, **−8<sup>0</sup> = x**, like **−2<sup>3</sup> = x**, will result in x being positive or negative.  **1 − 2<sup>3</sup> = −7** can be written as **1 + −2<sup>3</sup> = −7** or **1 + (−1) * (2<sup>3</sup>) = 7**.  Clearly the negative addition of terms is separate from the result of the exponent.